# Decoding airline fare basis codes

Tags: travel

I am looking for a program or web application to decode airline [fare basis codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fare_basis_code). Input: a fare basis code, e.g. `I7AUPNAC`, and perhaps airline name + date too. Output: human-readable text of the fare rules.

Any license, OS and price is fine.

The question was posted on https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47163/1810 by [Eugene O](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13320/eugene-o) but it got closed.

Answer (score 1):

[jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron) [pointed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/168804/1810) to [Expertflyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/):

> You can use a site such as [Expertflyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/) to look up fare rules. This is part of the premium subscription, but you can get a 5 days free trial.
>
> Go to fare information, enter your origin/destination (NYC/PAR), your dates of travel, and the fare basis code, and it'll show you the details for that fare. You can then ask for the fare rules, which are a long of rules which follow a number of conventions which sometimes make them quite hard to read for the uninitiated (because they are either generated automatically or used automatically, or both).
>
> The full rules are (answer continues after this short interruption):
>
> ```
> RULE APPLICATION AND OTHER CONDITIONS    NOTE - THE FOLLOWING TEXT IS INFORMATIONAL AND NOT
>    VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>    MAIN CABIN FARES
>    APPLICATION
>     CLASS OF SERVICE
>      THESE FARES APPLY FOR ECONOMY CLASS SERVICE.
>     CAPACITY LIMITATIONS
>      THE CARRIER SHALL LIMIT THE NUMBER OF PASSENGERS
>       CARRIED ON ANY ONE FLIGHT AT FARES GOVERNED BY
>       THIS RULE AND SUCH FARES WILL NOT NECESSARILY BE
>       AVAILABLE ON ALL FLIGHTS. THE NUMBER OF SEATS,
>       WHICH THE CARRIER SHALL MAKE AVAILABLE ON A GIVEN
>       FLIGHT, WILL BE DETERMINED BY THE CARRIERS BEST
>       JUDGEMENT.
> ELIGIBILITY      NO ELIGIBILITY REQUIREMENTS APPLY.
> DAY/TIME     OUTBOUND -
>      PERMITTED SUN THROUGH WED ON EACH TRANSATLANTIC
>      SECTOR.
>    INBOUND -
>      PERMITTED TUE THROUGH FRI ON EACH TRANSATLANTIC
>      SECTOR.
> SEASONALITY      OUTBOUND -
>      PERMITTED 14SEP21 THROUGH 23OCT21 OR 18NOV21 THROUGH
>      20NOV21 OR 15DEC21 THROUGH 17DEC21 OR 08APR22
>      THROUGH 06MAY22 OR 04SEP22 THROUGH 22OCT22 OR
>      17NOV22 THROUGH 19NOV22 OR 14DEC22 THROUGH 16DEC22
>      FOR EACH TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR. SEASON IS BASED ON
>      TRIP DATE.
>    INBOUND -
>      PERMITTED 14SEP21 THROUGH 30OCT21 OR 27NOV21 THROUGH
>      29NOV21 OR 29DEC21 THROUGH 08JAN22 OR 08APR22
>      THROUGH 13MAY22 OR 11SEP22 THROUGH 29OCT22 OR
>      26NOV22 THROUGH 28NOV22 OR 28DEC22 THROUGH 07JAN23
>      FOR EACH TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR. SEASON IS BASED ON
>      TRIP DATE.
> FLIGHT APPLICATION       THE FARE COMPONENT MUST NOT INCLUDE TRAVEL FROM/TO/VIA
>    BELARUS.
>    AND
>    THE FARE COMPONENT MUST NOT BE ON
>        ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>            ANY KL FLIGHT OPERATED BY EI
>            ANY AF FLIGHT OPERATED BY TO
>            ANY DL FLIGHT OPERATED BY OK.
>    AND
>    THE FARE COMPONENT MUST BE ON
>        ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING
>            ANY DL FLIGHT
>            ANY AF FLIGHT
>            ANY KL FLIGHT OPERATED BY KL
>            ANY VS FLIGHT OPERATED BY VS
>            ANY A5 FLIGHT
>            ANY HA FLIGHT.
> ADVANCE RESERVATIONS/TICKETING       CONFIRMED RESERVATIONS FOR ALL SECTORS ARE REQUIRED AT
>    LEAST 14 DAYS BEFORE DEPARTURE.
>    TICKETING MUST BE COMPLETED WITHIN 72 HOURS AFTER
>    RESERVATIONS ARE MADE OR AT LEAST 14 DAYS BEFORE
>    DEPARTURE WHICHEVER IS EARLIER.
> MINIMUM STAY     TRAVEL FROM INBOUND TRANSATLANTIC SECTOR MUST COMMENCE
>    NO EARLIER THAN 12 HOURS AFTER ARRIVAL AT THE
>    TURNAROUND.
> MAXIMUM STAY     TRAVEL FROM LAST STOPOVER MUST COMMENCE NO LATER THAN
>    12 MONTHS AFTER DEPARTURE FROM FARE ORIGIN.
> STOPOVERS    UNLIMITED STOPOVERS PERMITTED ON THE PRICING UNIT AT
>    USD 800.00 EACH.
> TRANSFERS    2 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
>      ANY COMBINATION OF THE FOLLOWING -
>       2 ONLINE ON DL
>         IN UNITED STATES IN EACH DIRECTION.
>    AND - 2 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN DL AND AF/DL/KL IN UNITED STATES/
>               CANADA IN EACH DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN AF AND AF/DL/KL IN UNITED STATES/
>               CANADA IN EACH DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN KL AND AF/DL/KL IN UNITED STATES/
>               CANADA IN EACH DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN WS AND AF/DL/KL IN CANADA IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN AF AND AF IN CANADA IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>    AND - 1 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN AF/DL/KL AND A5/AF IN FRANCE IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN AF/DL/KL AND AF/W2 IN FRANCE IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>    AND - 2 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN DL AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN AF AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN KL AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>               BETWEEN VS AND AF/DL/KL/VS IN EUROPE IN EACH
>               DIRECTION
>    AND - 1 TRANSFERS PERMITTED IN EACH DIRECTION
>            ANY COMBINATION OF THE FOLLOWING -
>             1 INTERLINE INCLUDING DL
>               IN HAWAII IN EACH DIRECTION.
>          FARE BREAK SURFACE SECTORS NOT PERMITTED AND
>          EMBEDDED SURFACE SECTORS PERMITTED ON THE FARE
>          COMPONENT.
> COMBINATIONS      DOUBLE OPEN JAWS NOT PERMITTED.
>    END-ON-END
>      END-ON-END COMBINATIONS PERMITTED. VALIDATE ALL FARE
>      COMBINATIONS.
>      PROVIDED -
>        COMBINATIONS ARE FOR CARRIER 7H/9K IN ANY RULE IN
>        TARIFF
>        CPR     - BETWEEN THE UNITED STATES-CANADA
>        DFR     - WITHIN THE UNITED STATES
>        VPCR    - BETWEEN PUERTO RICO/VIRGIN
>        ISLANDS-CANADA
>        VPDR    - BETWEEN PUERTO RICO/VIRGIN ISLANDS-THE
>        USA.
>    OPEN JAWS/ROUND TRIPS/CIRCLE TRIPS
>      FARES MAY BE COMBINED ON A HALF ROUND TRIP BASIS
>      -TO FORM SINGLE OPEN JAWS
>       MILEAGE OF THE OPEN SEGMENT MUST BE EQUAL/LESS THAN
>       MILEAGE OF THE SHORTEST FLOWN FARE COMPONENT.
>      -TO FORM ROUND TRIPS
>      -TO FORM CIRCLE TRIPS EXCEPT FOR AROUND-THE-WORLD
>       FARES.
>      PROVIDED -
>        COMBINATIONS ARE WITH ANY FARE FOR CARRIER DL/AF/
>        KL/AZ/VS IN ANY RULE IN TARIFF
>        IPRA    - BETWEEN USA/CA-AREA 2/3 AND GUAM-AREA 2
>        IPRAI   - BETWEEN THE USA/CANADA-AREA 2/3 VIA ATL
>        IPRSAA2 - BETWEEN THE WESTERN HEMISPHERE-AREA 2
>        VIA ATL
>        IPRSAA3 - SOUTH ATLANTIC/CENTRAL/SOUTH AMERICA/
>        MEXICO/CARIBBEAN/GREENLAND/ST PIERRE ET MIQUELON -
>        AREA 3.
>        COMBINATIONS ARE WITH ANY FARE FOR CARRIER DL/AF/
>        KL/AZ/VS IN RULE 2222/4444 IN TARIFF
>        ATDLR   - BETWEEN AREA 1-AREA 2/3 AND GUAM-AREA 2
>        OR RULE 2222/4444 IN TARIFF
>        TAPVR   - BETWEEN AREA 1-AREA 2/3 AND GUAM-AREA 2
>        OR ANY RULE IN TARIFF
>        FBRINPV - BETWEEN USA/CA-AREA 1/2/3.
>    NOTE - THE CITY PAIRS BELOW ARE CONSIDERED THE SAME
>           POINT -
>           BUR-LGB  BUR-SNA  BWI-WAS  FLL-MIA  LAX-BUR
>           LAX-LGB  LAX-ONT  LAX-SNA  LGB-SNA  NYC-EWR
>           OAK-SFO  OAK-SJC  ONT-BUR  ONT-LGB  ONT-SNA
>           SFO-SJC
> BLACKOUT DATES       NO BLACKOUT DATES APPLY.
> SURCHARGES       FARE RULE
>    IF INFANT WITHOUT A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2.
>      THERE IS NO MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE PER
>      DIRECTION PER ANY PASSENGER.
>    THE PROVISIONS BELOW APPLY ONLY AS FOLLOWS -
>    WHEN TICKETS ARE SOLD IN CHINA.
>      ORIGINATING UNITED STATES -
>        MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 400.00 PER
>        DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER
>        ANY PASSENGER.
>  
>    GENERAL RULE - APPLY UNLESS OTHERWISE SPECIFIED
>    IF INFANT WITHOUT A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2.
>      THERE IS NO MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE PER
>      DIRECTION PER ANY PASSENGER.
>    THE PROVISIONS BELOW APPLY ONLY AS FOLLOWS -
>    TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR AF.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR AM.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR AZ.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR DJ.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR KE.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR KL.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR KQ.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR ME.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR OA.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR OK.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR TN.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VA.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VN.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VT.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR PS.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR VS.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR 9U.
>    OR - TICKETS MUST BE ISSUED ON THE STOCK OF DL OR 9W.
>      THERE IS NO MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE PER
>      DIRECTION PER ANY PASSENGER.
>          NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>           YR FEE MAY APPLY
>      AND - ORIGINATING UNITED STATES -
>        MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 6.75 PER
>        DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER
>        ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA AMS.
>        AND - MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 7.00 PER
>              DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE
>              FARE PER ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA ROM.
>    MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 320.00 PER
>    DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER ANY
>    PASSENGER.
>      AND - ORIGINATING UNITED STATES -
>        MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 6.75 PER
>        DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE FARE PER
>        ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA AMS.
>        AND - MISCELLANEOUS/OTHER SURCHARGE OF USD 7.00 PER
>              DIRECTION WILL BE ADDED TO THE APPLICABLE
>              FARE PER ANY PASSENGER FOR FROM/TO/VIA ROM.
> ACCOMPANIED TRAVEL       ACCOMPANIED TRAVEL NOT REQUIRED.
> TRAVEL RESTRICTIONS      NO TRAVEL DATE RESTRICTIONS APPLY.
> SALES RESTRICTIONS       TICKETS MAY NOT BE SOLD IN VENEZUELA/CUBA/ZIMBABWE/
>    CAMEROON/CHAD/CONGO BRAZZAVILLE/GABON.
>    TICKETS MAY ONLY BE SOLD IN AREA 1/AREA 2/AREA 3.
> PENALTIES  *SPECIAL EMERGENCY RULES
>  *SUBJECT TO CHANGE AT ANYTIME
>  
>    ORIGINATING AREA 1 -
>    FOR TICKETING ON/BEFORE 30APR21/FOR TRAVEL ON/AFTER
>    01MAR20 AND ON/BEFORE 31DEC22
>      IF TRAVEL ON THIS FARE COMPONENT MUST COMMENCE BY
>      MIDNIGHT ON 31DEC22.
>      CANCELLATIONS
>      
>        CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED FOR CANCEL/NO-SHOW.
>      
>      CHANGES
>      
>        CHANGES PERMITTED.
>          NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>           -FOR INFORMATION ON TICKET REISSUE PROCEDURES
>           SEE DELTA/S INTERNATIONAL CONTRACT OF CARRIAGE
>           RULE 22 REROUTING
>    ORIGINATING EUROPE -
>    FOR TICKETING ON/BEFORE 30APR21/FOR TRAVEL ON/AFTER
>    01MAR20 AND ON/BEFORE 31DEC22
>      IF TRAVEL ON THIS FARE COMPONENT MUST COMMENCE BY
>      MIDNIGHT ON 31DEC22.
>      CHANGES
>      
>        CHANGES PERMITTED.
>          NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>           -FOR INFORMATION ON TICKET REISSUE PROCEDURES
>           SEE DELTA/S INTERNATIONAL CONTRACT OF CARRIAGE
>           RULE 22 REROUTING
>    GENERAL RULE - APPLY UNLESS OTHERWISE SPECIFIED
>    CANCELLATIONS
>    
>      CANCELLATIONS PERMITTED.
>    
>    CHANGES
>    
>      CHANGES PERMITTED.
>          NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>           ----TICKET VALIDITY----
>           TICKET IS VALID FOR 1 YEAR FROM THE ORIGINAL DATE
>           OF ISSUANCE AND TRAVEL MUST COMMENCE WITHIN THIS
>           VALIDITY PERIOD. ONCE TRAVEL HAS COMMENCED THEN
>           ALL TRAVEL MUST BE COMPLETED WITHIN 1 YEAR FROM
>           THE DATE ON WHICH TRAVEL COMMENCED.
>           IF A TICKET IS EXCHANGED OR REISSUED -
>                1. A WHOLLY UNUSED TICKET MUST BE
>                EXCHANGED WITHIN THE ORIGINAL VALIDITY
>                PERIOD OF 1 YEAR AND WILL BE GIVEN A NEW
>                TICKET ISSUE DATE BASED ON THE DATE OF
>                EXCHANGE.
>                2. IF TRAVEL HAS COMMENCED THEN THE
>                TICKET MUST BE REISSUED AND ALL TRAVEL
>                COMPLETED WITHIN 1 YEAR FROM THE DATE ON
>                WHICH TRAVEL COMMENCED.
>           .
>           -FOR INFORMATION ON TICKET REISSUE PROCEDURES
>           SEE DELTA/S INTERNATIONAL CONTRACT OF CARRIAGE
>           RULE 22 REROUTING
> HIP/MILEAGE EXCEPTIONS       NO HIP OR MILEAGE EXCEPTIONS APPLY.
> TICKET ENDORSEMENTS      THE ORIGINAL AND THE REISSUED TICKET MUST BE ANNOTATED
>    - RFNDABLE - AND - CHNGS PERMITTED - IN THE
>    ENDORSEMENT BOX.
> CHILDREN DISCOUNTS       CNN/ACCOMPANIED CHILD PSGR 2-11 - CHARGE 100 PERCENT
>      OF THE FARE.
>          TICKET DESIGNATOR - CH AND PERCENT APPLIED.
>      MUST BE ACCOMPANIED ON ALL FLIGHTS IN THE SAME
>        COMPARTMENT BY ADULT PSGR 18 OR OLDER.
>    OR - INS/INFANT WITH A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2 - CHARGE 100
>           PERCENT OF THE FARE.
>               TICKET DESIGNATOR - CH AND PERCENT APPLIED.
>           MUST BE ACCOMPANIED ON ALL FLIGHTS IN THE SAME
>             COMPARTMENT BY ADULT PSGR 18 OR OLDER.
>    OR - INF/INFANT WITHOUT A SEAT PSGR UNDER 2 - CHARGE 10
>           PERCENT OF THE FARE.
>               TICKET DESIGNATOR - IN AND PERCENT APPLIED.
>           MUST BE ACCOMPANIED ON ALL FLIGHTS IN THE SAME
>             COMPARTMENT BY ADULT PSGR 18 OR OLDER.
>          NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>           THE AGE LIMITS REFERRED TO IN THIS RULE
>           SHALL BE THOSE IN EFFECT ON THE DATE OF
>           COMMENCEMENT OF TRAVEL.  EXCEPTION- INFANTS WHO
>           REACH THEIR 2ND BIRTHDAY DURING THEIR TRAVEL WILL
>           BE REQUIRED TO OCCUPY A SEAT ON THE OUBOUND AND
>           INBOUND FLIGHTS.  THE CHILDS FARE MUST BE APPLIED
>           FOR THE WHOLE JOURNEY.
>    OR - UNN/UNACCOMPANIED CHILD PSGR 5-14 - CHARGE 100
>           PERCENT OF THE FARE.
>               TICKET DESIGNATOR - UM AND PERCENT APPLIED.
>          NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>           UNACCOMPANIED CHILDREN UNDER 5 YEARS OF AGE WILL
>           NOT BE ACCEPTED FOR CARRIAGE UNDER ANY CONDITIONS.
>           UNACCOMPANIED CHILDREN AGES 5 THROUGH 7 MAY TRAVEL
>           ON NON-STOP FLIGHTS ONLY AND MAY NOT CONNECT TO
>           OTHER AIRLINES.
>           CHILDREN AGES 8 THROUGH 14 MAY TRAVEL
>           UNACCOMPANIED ON DELTAS NON-STOP OR CONNECTING
>           FLIGHTS - BUT MAY NOT CONNECT TO OTHER AIRLINES
>           WITH THE EXCEPTION OF DELTA CONNECTION/KLM AND
>           AIR FRANCE.
> TOUR CONDUCTOR DISCOUNTS           NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.
>           DISCOUNTS APPLY
> AGENT DISCOUNTS      NO DISCOUNTS FOR SALE AGENTS.
> ALL OTHER DISCOUNTS      NO DISCOUNTS FOR OTHERS.
> MISCELLANEOUS PROVISIONS     NO PROVISIONS APPLY.
> FARE BY RULE     NOT APPLICABLE.
> GROUPS       NO GROUP PROVISIONS APPLY.
> TOURS    NO TOUR PROVISIONS APPLY.
> VISIT ANOTHER COUNTRY    NO VISIT ANOTHER COUNTRY PROVISIONS APPLY.
> DEPOSITS     NO DEPOSIT PROVISIONS APPLY.
> VOLUNTARY CHANGES    IN THE EVENT OF CHANGES TO TICKETED FLIGHTS
>    BEFORE DEPARTURE OF JOURNEY AND WITHIN TICKET VALIDITY
>    CERTAIN DOMESTIC REISSUE PROVISIONS MAY BE OVERRIDDEN
>    BY THOSE OF DL INTERNATIONAL FARES
>    NO CHARGE FOR REISSUE CHARGE HIGHEST FEE OF ALL
>    CHANGED FARE COMPONENTS - CATEGORY 19 DISCOUNTS APPLY
>    AND
>      REPRICE USING FARES IN EFFECT TODAY
>      PROVIDED ALL OF THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS ARE MET-
>      1. WHEN NO INTL COUPONS REMAIN - ALL NEW TRAVEL
>      MUST BE DOMESTIC
>      2. AF/DL/KL/VS FARES ARE USED
>      3. ADV RES IS MEASURED FROM REISSUE DATE TO
>      DEPARTURE OF PRICING UNIT
>      OR -
>      REPRICE USING CURRENT FARES - ONLY BOOKING CODE
>      CHANGES PERMITTED
>      PROVIDED ALL OF THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS ARE MET-
>      1. NO CHANGE TO FARE BREAKS
>      2. WHEN NO INTL COUPONS REMAIN - ALL NEW TRAVEL
>      MUST BE DOMESTIC
>      3. SAME TRAVEL DATES
>      4. AF/DL/KL/VS FARES ARE USED
>      5. ADV RES IS MEASURED FROM REISSUE DATE TO
>      DEPARTURE OF JOURNEY
>    WHEN CHANGE RESULTS IN LOWER FARE SUBTRACT RESIDUAL
>    FROM THE PENALTY THEN ADD-COLLECT/REFUND
>    ENDORSEMENT BOX - HIGHER NON-REF AMT AND NEW
>    ENDORSEMENTS.
>    OR -
>    AFTER DEPARTURE OF JOURNEY AND WITHIN TICKET VALIDITY
>    CERTAIN DOMESTIC REISSUE PROVISIONS MAY BE OVERRIDDEN
>    BY THOSE OF DL INTERNATIONAL FARES
>    NO CHARGE FOR REISSUE CHARGE HIGHEST FEE OF ALL CHANGED
>    FARE COMPONENTS - CATEGORY 19 DISCOUNTS APPLY AND
>      REPRICE USING FARES IN EFFECT WHEN TKT WAS ISSUED
>      PROVIDED ALL OF THE FOLLOWING CONDITIONS ARE MET-
>      1. NO CHANGE TO 1ST FARE COMPONENT
>      2. WHEN NO INTL COUPONS REMAIN - ALL NEW TRAVEL
>      MUST BE DOMESTIC
>      3. FULLY FLOWN FARE NOT REPRICED TO FURTHER POINT
>      4. AF/AM/DL/KE/KL/VA/VS FARES ARE USED
>      5. DL ANY FARE TYPE EXCEPT EOU/ERH/ERU/PRU ARE USED
>      6. ALL RULE AND BOOKING CODE PROVISIONS ARE MET
>      EXCEPT ACCOMPANIED TRAVEL
>      7. ADV RES IS MEASURED FROM ORIGINAL TKT DATE TO
>      DEPARTURE OF PRICING UNIT
>    REFUND VIA ORIGINAL FORM OF PAYMENT
>    ENDORSEMENT BOX - HIGHER NON-REF AMT AND NEW
>    ENDORSEMENTS.
> .
> VOLUNTARY REFUNDS    CHECK CATEGORY 16 OR CONTACT CARRIER FOR DETAILS.
> NEGOTIATED FARES     NOT APPLICABLE.
> INTERNATIONAL CONSTRUCTION       NOT A CONSTRUCTED FARE
> ```